VS Code JavaFX property getter/setter generation
I've recently switched from IntelliJ IDEA to VS Code to develop a JavaFX application. The "Extension Pack for Java" seems to have everything I need and I can build and debug my application just fine.
One thing I'm missing from IntelliJ is it's support for generating JavaFX property getter and setter through the code generation menu.
In VS Code such an option is still available via the "Source Action (Alt+Ins)" menu. However, this seems to support only simple Beans getter and setter. Is there any plugin to provide the support I need? Otherwise, where can I reach out to suggest support for this?
Here's an example of what code is generated by selecting Source Action -> Generate Getters and Setters:
public class Properties {
    private BooleanProperty property; // the property field in question

    // simple Beans-style getters and setters
    public BooleanProperty getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(BooleanProperty property) {
        this.property = property;
    }    
}

But what I actually need for JavaFX to recognize these properties via reflection is this:
public class Properties {
    private BooleanProperty property; // the property field in question

    // proper set of getters / setters - note the additional "enabledProperty" method
    public boolean getProperty() {
        return property.get();
    }

    public BooleanProperty propertyProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(boolean value) {
        this.property.set(value);
    }
}


Kinda off-topic, but Netbeans 8 had a plugin that did this. The latest version no longer has that plugin. I ended up creating a JavaFX app with a TextArea. I input the instance variables on new lines like StringProperty test\nBooleanProperty isTest\nObjectProperty<SomeObject> someObject, and that app will generate the whole class.

If an existing feature doesn't meet your expectations. You can submit a feature request at GitHub.

There is an old article on the JavaFX property architecture with a short cookbook, but it is a bit dated, and, in practice, most of those patterns aren't used - so code generation for them is not needed.  For 90% of cases though, what you have in your question with the additional property accessor (and what Idea generates) is just fine, perhaps with an addition to cover ReadOnlyWrappers and ReadOnlyProperties.  Just some info that might help you scope a feature request should you decide to make one.
